# Company name spelled incorrectly

Tags: visas

I am traveling to Dublin for a business meeting. Everything is correct but the company name is spelled incorrectly. It should be Bentley whereas it is written ar Bently. I got a BIVS visa. Will that be an issue ?

Comment: Where is it spelled incorrectly?

Comment: It is spelled on my Visa

Comment: It's unlikely to be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Unlikely.  The visa is really more about you, not who you're visiting. As long as your names and details are correct, that's really what the immigration officer is concerned with.